# Rails 3 autocomplete with JQuery - need to clean up my controller code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, autocomplete

My autocomplet works, and it looks decent enough, but oh boy, the controller is a mess.  The autocomplete searches across multiple models which does not help things, and totalling up the found sets ect - there are country flags for customers etc.

I'd like to extract this to a partial ideally or another way to make the code easier to deal with.

```
  def autocomplete
      customer_count = (Customer.select("company").where("LOWER(company) LIKE ? AND deleted != ?", "#{params[:term].downcase}%", true).count) + (Product.select("model_number,description").where("LOWER(description) LIKE ? OR LOWER(model_number) LIKE ? AND deleted != ?", "#{params[:term].downcase}%", "#{params[:term].downcase}%", true).count) + (Order.where("LOWER(order_number) LIKE ? AND deleted != true","#{params[:term].downcase}%").count)
      @customers = [{:label => (customer_count > 1 ? "<div style='font-weight: bold; text-align: left;'>Show all #{customer_count} records</div" : customer_count > 0 ? '' : "<div style='font-weight: bold; text-align: left;'>No records found</div>"), :link => "/customers?company=#{params[:term].downcase}"}]
      @customers.concat(Customer.select("id, company, country").where("LOWER(company) LIKE ? AND deleted != ?", "#{params[:term].downcase}%", true).limit(24).collect{|customer|{:label=>("<div style='float:left;margin-top:4px;margin-right:8px;'><img alt='Mini_usa' src='/images/#{customer.country_div}'/></div> #{customer.company}").html_safe,:link =>"/customers/#{customer.id}"}})
      @customers.concat(Product.select("id, model_number, description").where("LOWER(description) LIKE ? OR LOWER(model_number) LIKE ? AND deleted != ?","#{params[:term].downcase}%","#{params[:term].downcase}%",true).limit(24).collect{|product|{:label => ("#{product.model_number.titlecase}&nbsp;#{product.description.titlecase}").html_safe,:link =>"/products/#{product.model_number}"}})
      @customers.concat(Order.select("id, order_number").where("LOWER(order_number) LIKE ? AND deleted != true","#{params[:term].downcase}%").limit(24).collect{ |order| { :label => ("#{order.order_number}").html_safe, :link =>"/orders/#{order.id}" } })
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you make `autocomplete` (or perhaps `search` is a better name for the context) methods for each individual model, then call and combine  them each from your controller? This keeps the responsibility of knowing *how* to search where the data itself lies (in the model).

In general you want to favor putting logic in your model, not your controller.

Comment: So you're saying that each model needs its own self.search(term) method, "term" being passed in by the ActionController that processes the form (possibly products#index)...?

Comment: @james_dunn_jr Yup! Controller takes in the parameters from the user, then asks the model to search for records that match it, because the controller shouldn't know *how* to search, only how to *ask* for search results.

Comment: @fatfrog Put them in the view where they belong `:)`

Comment: according to the Railscast tutorial, server side search it's done in the controller and I can't figure out how to get it out : http://railscasts.com/episodes/102-auto-complete-association-revised?view=asciicast

Comment: I can't watch that as I don't subscribe to Railscasts Pro. Just put it in a new view and call `render` with that view. Instead of `concat`ing your objects in the controller, keep them separate so the view can manipulate them accordingly for rendering.